# diff of config files showing only uncommented lines

Tags: diff

Consider the need to use 'diff' to compare two files with many commented lines, such as system configuration files. (For example, the files could be /etc/cups/cups-files.conf.pacnew and /etc/cups/cups-files.conf.)

I would like to **ignore** differences of any lines that are commented out such as these:

```
< #DocumentRoot /usr/share/cups/doc
---
> #DocumentRoot /usr/share/cups/doc-root
```

I only want to see differences of active (uncommented) lines.

(I would also like to ignore whitespace differences. I mention that for completeness in case the solution for the above interferes with using the the `-w` option.)

Comment: Other than `-I`?

Comment: @Ignacio `-I` only works if you have no mixed hunks – *e.g.* if you use `-I '^#'`, but add one commented line followed by a non-commented line, you’ll see both in the `diff` output because they’re part of the same hunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the commented lines before comparing the files:

```
diff -u -w <(grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' /etc/cups/cups-files.conf.pacnew) <(grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' /etc/cups/cups-files.conf)
```

That way `diff` will only see uncommented lines, and will only compare those.

Comment: can this be easily modified to work when the comment symbol is not in column 0? (That would be true in the case of leading whitespace.)

Comment: This does not account for lines that may have comments *at the end of them*.  A line that contains `DocumentRoot /usr/share/cups/doc #some comment here` would be excluded, regardless of whether the "active" part is different between files.

Comment: @MountainX see the update.

Comment: @Hiko no, it only excludes lines consisting solely of a comment.

Comment: @HikoHaieto: Default config files are almost never commented in that manner.

Comment: @Hiko one could use `sed` to delete comments anywhere, taking care to handle quoted `#` symbols ;-).

Comment: Same idea using sed (both work): diff <(sed -e 's/^#.*$//' -e '/^$/d' file1.txt) <(sed -e 's/^#.*$//' -e '/^$/d' file2.txt)